# How to call javascript function for bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to add a datepicker to my form using the bootstrap framework. I'm very green with front-end dev and am having difficulty understanding where the code goes and why the examples I'm using aren't working. Here's my jsp page as a whole:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="form"  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

  <html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link href="https://ui.oreillyauto.com/ui/css/oreillybs-2.04r2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ui.oreillyauto.com/ui/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">   </script>
  <script src="https://ui.oreillyauto.com/ui/js/jquery/plugins/oreillybs-2.04r1.js"></script>

<div class="page-header">
<h1>
    <spring:message code="title.training"/>
</h1>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="assignTraining" action="/javawebtraining/userTraining/save" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><spring:message code="directions.assigntrain"/></legend>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="tmNumber"><spring:message code="label.tmnum"/></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <form:input path="tmNumber" class="input-xlarge" maxLength="10" />
                    <form:errors path="tmNumber" cssClass="form-errors" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <input name="date" class="src_date" type="textarea" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" id="date" required>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function($){
                    $("#date").datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
                    });
                </script>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="moduleIds"><spring:message code="label.modules"/></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <c:forEach items="${modules}" var="module">
                        <label class="checkbox"><form:checkbox path="moduleIds" value="${module.id}" /> ${module.title}</label>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <form:errors path="moduleIds" cssClass="form-errors" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><spring:message code="button.submit"/></button>
                <a href="/javawebtraining/module/admin" class="btn"><spring:message code="button.cancel"/></a>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have no clue what I'm doing. I just started adding sources and links because I figured it couldn't hurt. Right now, the datepicker textbox shows as well as the icon, but the calender doesn't pop up. I'm guessing it's my javascript function, so how would I correctly call my function so this datepicker works correctly? Any simple explanation of what's really going on would be a plus too. Thanks

Comment: twitter bootstrap doesn't have a datepicker component. Are you using a 3rd pary one? If so which one?

Comment: I was looking at this [page](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/) and hoping to use the middle image layout. Having difficulty understanding where exactly all of those snippets of code go and what some of them even do.

Answer (score 0):

To get [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) running correctly, your website should contain the following 3 files:

- `twitter-bootstrap` css file
- `bootstrap-datepicker` css file
- `bootstrap-datepicker` js file

[Here is mini demo project for you to try out.](http://jsfiddle.net/jzelenkov/96vfu37o/4/) CSS part contains only that of the `bootstrap-datepicker` project. In order to get the icons working another file should be loaded as well. It's called glyphicons and should be located in `css/fonts` directory. [Read more about how to use glyphicons.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use)

`bootstrap-datepicker` contains [2 different css files](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/css). One for modern browsers and another one for older browsers with prefixes.

Are your `js` and `css` files being loaded by the browser? All files hosted on https://ui.oreillyauto.com/ domain return `404` error for me.

I don't see any other issues with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is for my work so most files are hosted on their servers. Forgive the ignorance, but how do I tell if my js and css files are being loaded by the browser?

Comment: You could look it up in the developer tools of your browser. You should see that on the network tab.

Comment: Here is an intro for firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor and chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 0):

in your js file add the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.src_date').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true
  })
;
```

this might help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would I add this in between my <script> tags then? Sorry, still unsure about the js/html setup.